# Topic of the Week

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, challenge

This is a quick way to expand the scope of the site and generate new questions and answers.

**How it works:** - One topic will be designated each week starting Friday 0:00 (EST) and ending Thursday 23:59 (EST).  The current topic will be listed below.

**How to enter** - In order to participate, simply tag your question with the topic's tag to be eligible.  You must also be a **registered** member of Movies.SE.

The winner will be determined by the amount of upvotes the question garners.  In the case of a tie, view count will be used.  Your question must **not** be closed and/or deleted in order to qualify.  Your question must also be asked within the promotion week.

**This is all well and good, but what do *I* get from this?** - Honestly, at the moment, nothing.  There are no prizes as we are a **Beta** site and do not have the financial backing of StackExchange at all for contests.  This is purely maintained by the moderators with user input as to what the topics should be.  That doesn't mean, however, that this is all for naught.  As stated, this is an effort to improve the traffic, visibility, and overall quality of the site.

**Choosing the topic of the week:** If you have suggestions for a future topic, please leave them as answers to this post. Topics must be trackable with a tag, meaning that specific directors, actors, television shows, movies and franchises are encouraged. Basically anything that currently has a tag is probably fair game. Topics will be chosen based on either their timely and increased notoriety or to expand the M&TV's content and scope.  If you disagree with a topic, also post it as an answer with why you disagree.

Please note that it's currently just us mods running the topic of the week and we haven't gotten a large sounding board for what topics to run when.  If you feel something shoudl be ran at a specific time, please add an answer to this question, or @ the mods in chat.  This is for everyone, we're just keeping the lights on.

---

**Current Topic:**

Due to certain factors, ToTW has been put on hold for the time being.

========================================================================

**Scheduled Topics:**

- [the-man-with-the-iron-fist](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-man-with-the-iron-fist) 11/02/2012 - 11/08/2012
- [lincoln](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lincoln) 11/09/2012 - 11/15/2012
- [twilight-series](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twilight-series) 11/16/2012 - 11/22/2012
- [life-of-pi](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/life-of-pi) 11/23/2012 - 11/29/2012
- [universal-soldiers-series](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/universal-soldiers-series) 11/30/2012 - 12/06/2012
- [hyde-park](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyde-park) 12/07/2012 - 12/13/2012
- [the-hobbit](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hobbit) 12/14/2012 - 12/20/2012
- [the-impossible](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-impossible) 12/21/2012 - 12/27/2012

**Completed Topics and winners**

- [cloud-atlas](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud-atlas) 10/26/2012 - 11/01/2012  **No Questions Asked**
- [paranormal-activity](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paranormal-activity) series 10/19/2012 - 10/25/2012  **No Questions Asked**
- [seven-psychopaths](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seven-psychopaths) 10/12/2012 - 10/18/2012 **No Questions asked**
- Taken Week 10/5/2012 - 10/11/2012 [**Saariko**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/4537/how-did-liam-neeson-know-his-location-in-taken-2)
- [time-travel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-travel) movies 09/28/2012 - 10/04/2012 [**Shane Finneran**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/4459/in-la-jetee-does-the-time-travelers-body-stay-in-the-present-time)
- [judge-dredd](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judge-dredd)[dredd-3d](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dredd-3d) 09/21/2012 - 09/27/2012 [**BamfTheNightAway**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/4323/is-dredd-3d-an-adaptation-of-a-specific-comic-storyline)
- [resident-evil](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil) series week 9/14/2012 - 9/20/2012 [**Ankit Sharma**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/4159/why-alice-is-chosen-as-the-main-protagonist-in-resident-evil)
- [indiana-jones](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indiana-jones) 9/7/2012 - 9/13/2012 [**Vijin Paulraj**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/4104/how-did-indy-know-not-to-look-into-the-ark)
- [horror](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror) event 8/24/2012 - 9/6/2012 [**SystemDown**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3981/cultural-basis-of-asian-ghost-lady)
- Expendables week 8/17/2012 - 8/23/2012 [No questions asked]
- Bourne Franchise 8/10/2012 - 8/16/2012 [**tylershads**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3735/what-is-the-reason-behind-choosing-a-different-character-for-legacy)
- Philip K. Dick Week 8/3/2012 - 8/9/2012 [**Shane Finneran**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3685/did-any-character-in-a-scanner-darkly-resemble-philip-k-dick-himself)
- Batman Special Event 7/20/2012 - 8/2/2012 [**tylershads**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3369/why-does-bane-protect-the-girl)
- [analysis](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) 7/13/2012 - 7/19/2012 [**stevve**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3311/why-was-being-john-malkovich-based-around-john-malkovich)
- Spider-Man franchise 7/6/2012 – 7/12/2012 [**KevinHowell**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3251/why-is-gwen-stacy-emma-stone-in-the-amazing-spider-man)
- [seth-macfarlane](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seth-macfarlane) 6/29/2012 - 7/5/2012 [**Morpheus**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3082/does-johnny-bravo-ever-get-a-girl-friend)
- [pixar](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pixar) 6/15/2012 - 6/28/2012 [**VijinPaulraj**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3023/why-doesnt-andy-have-a-dad-in-toy-story)
- [true-blood](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/true-blood) 6/15/2012 – 6/21/2012 [**TylerShads**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/what-was-the-reasoning-behind-sookies-decision)
- [ridley-scott](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ridley-scott) 6/8/2012 - 6/14/2012 [**stevve**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2720/what-does-the-origami-represent-in-blade-runner)

---

**Planned Topics:**

- [men-in-black](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/men-in-black)
- [game-of-thrones](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) (Planned for Season 3)
- [dexter](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dexter) (Planned for season 7)
- [animation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation)
- [book-adaptation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-adaptation)
- [comedy](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comedy)
- [joss-whedon](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joss-whedon)
- [the-hunger-games](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hunger-games)
- [buffy-vampire-slayer-tv](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffy-vampire-slayer-tv)
- [dredd](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dredd)
- [clint-eastwood](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clint-eastwood)
- [sitcoms](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sitcoms)
- [plot-inconsistency](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-inconsistency)
- [spin-off](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spin-off)
- [animation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation)
- [arrested-development](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arrested-development)
- [classics](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classics)
- [special-effects](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-effects)
- [documentary](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentary)
- [tim-burton](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tim-burton)
- [johnny-depp](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/johnny-depp)
- [steven-spielberg](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steven-spielberg)
- [mad-men](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mad-men)
- [sam-raimi](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sam-raimi) (Planned for Oz)
- [david-fincher](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/david-fincher)

---

[*All credit goes to [Brett White of Scifi.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1138/topic-of-the-week-contest-updated-may-7#comment4440_1138) for allowing me to <strike>steal</strike> borrow a template for the idea.*]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the Community Bulletin, you can easily see which topic we are running this week and a click of the link brings you right back here for more details.

Right before the current week runs out, you should be able to see next week's topic in queue.

[image]