# Do we require more mods?

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderation

Its just my opinion that we required more mods.
Currently we have only three mods `TylerShads`, `DForck42` and `iandotkelly`.
All Three of them are good in their work and easily available on chat but the fact is that our site is in growing fast and during the past week there are no updates done by mods especially on [Topic of the week](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/479/topic-of-the-week?cb=1), and even on chat, I get no response. Its not a complaint at all.

I am just saying that if we have more mods then we will have more probability of getting an active mod at all times. In my opinion 3 mods are too little for a developing site and we should have an Election etc. to appoint more mods if possible. Or we can select them from the list of [top user](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all)

I am not pointing at anyone so don't misunderstand me. I am open for a discussion.

Comment: As stated before, the reason for this is work schedule interference and vacations.

Comment: @TylerShads now i don't see any problem at all in three mods and want to delete the question but can't able to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do understand your thoughts - no criticism taken.  I was on vacation last week, Tylershads is this week.  We've all been unusually busy, and chat has been quiet between us.

I did note the comment about the TOTW, we have been remiss here - the banner was updated but not the post. Either DForck42 or myself will deal with that over the next few hours.

Honestly, I don't think the volume of this site warrants more mods (not a self serving statement honestly).  Like DForck42 I do prioritize keeping on top of flags and proposed edits.  Average time to respond to flags in August is 57 minutes, actually better than average.

The best argument I can see for another, or an alternate mod - is that all the mods are based in the USA, over 2 time zones.  It might be good to have a broader spread.

Answer (score 4):

I am currently okay with concept of the three mods so far. I don't see the reason to nominate mod based on just one instance of a week. Plus we are a Beta community and i do see the trend of increasing questions with topic of week announcement but I think still with increase three should be able to cover it.

Plus there are plenty of users over 2000 points form the list you posted in your question who i believe have the access to moderator tools as well who can step in as needed.

Comment: +1 For placing opinion.But... `Topic of the Week` is having a big hand in our increasing question last days but now its decreased too because of no update about `Topic of the Week` from more the a week. SE also have a provision of election and community can decide the mods. I am also ok with three mods but if its possible then we can elect more.

Comment: what do you mean its not updated? i see this week as expendables week

Comment: plus the major surge so far i have seen in the community was during Dark knight rises and i thought current mods covered it very well.

Comment: go to http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/479/topic-of-the-week?cb=1 , there is no update about TOW there and even their is no declaration of last week winner too.

Answer (score 3):

I've been a bit busy here lately, and Tylersahds is on vacation ro something.  I've been meaning to update the TOTW but I just haven't had time the last few days.  I'll try and do it today.

Other than that, the site's been pretty calm.  I do keep check on flags and new post though, and there haven't been many the last little bit.

Comment: Yes i agree that these days site is too quite, so i though more no of mod can make it more active but might be i am wrong.