# Disambiguation in Community Bulletin board

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

## Attention to Moderators

There are two questions showing up in our Community Bulletin board and both are going to ends in same days i,e 3days as of now. But according to [Topic of the Week](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/479/topic-of-the-week) **Indiana Jones** topic is being in the Scheduled Topics and should be active on 9/7/2012 to 9/13/2012. According to [Topic of the Week](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/479/topic-of-the-week), Horror topic should be in current topic and only ends on 9/6/2012.

Comment: Whoops! I fixed it.  Thank yo for pointing that out.