# Topic Challenge 11/05/14 - 11/19/14: Bring on your Interstellar questions!

Tags: discussion, community-event, challenge

As the inclined cinema enthusiast might have noticed, this week sees *Christopher Nolan*'s [*Interstellar*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816692/) opening in theatres in many parts of the world. And I thought this might be a good chance for a little **two-weeks topic challenge**, in the spirit of our good old (but cancelled) [topic of the week](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/479/49). Hoping that the movie follows *Nolan*'s tradition of providing an excellent mixture of art, depth and big-screen entertainment, this movie is on the one hand famous enough to be seen by a large crowd, but might on the other hand elicit some very interesting questions, and is universally awaited enough for people to watch it as soon as possible and come looking for good information about it, which makes it an excellent candidate for a topic challenge around a single movie.

### So it's time to bring on all your great questions about anything *Interstellar*!

<sup>And don't forget to tag 'em appropriately with [interstellar](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interstellar).</sup>

While this is only a rather inofficial challenge without any material prizes for the winners, I still hope to encourage some interesting questions and exhaustive answers. The asked questions will be listed here once the challenge is over (**at 11/19/14 12:00 UTC**), with the highest-voted question and answer winning <s>a pre-ordered Special Edition BluRay of the movie</s> the honor of being mentioned specifically.

<sub>And I want to appologize to the community for not asking about any ideas beforehand, impudently hopping over the [1st step of a topic challenge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/162011). This was a rather short-term idea and is more of a first test to bring back some kind of topic challenge. So feel free to downvote this question if you consider this an awfully terrible idea.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So...the inofficial topic challenge is over and there was a whole of **31** non-closed questions asked about the movie.

**The top-voted question** (with a score of 14), which also features the two highest-voted answers (with scores of 25 and 20) would be this one by [*Ankit*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/301), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

[Why wasn't Interstellar shot in 3D?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27012/49)

**The other questions asked, in order of votes are:**

[How did Murph know about Edmunds?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27041/49)

[In what time does Interstellar take place?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27011/49)

[How could the human race be saved in Interstellar?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27218/49)

[How was Plan B supposed to work?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27073/49)

[Why was the wormhole in Interstellar placed near Saturn?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27316/49)

[What is the significance of Murphy's law?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27111/49)

[How did Cooper find the location of NASA from the patterns?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27027/49)

[How did the watch do what it did?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27037/49)

[How does Cooper get out of the black hole?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27199/49)

[What was Mann's motivation?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27083/49)

[How did Murph figure it out?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27029/49)

[Connection between Interstellar and 'Flora's Letter'?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/26927/49)

[Why did Mann's base explode?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27125/49)

[If Cooper wanted to stay, why did he send the NASA Coordinates?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27159/49)

[Who are "they" in Interstellar?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27015/49)

[Why the Robots were like this?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27141/49)

[In what way was Murph's quantum data from her Dad's watch helpful?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27040/49)

[Why does time flow differently on Miller's planet?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27194/49)

[Is Nolan citing Borges?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27247/49)

[IMAX DMR vs 35mm film](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/26983/49)

[About Gargantua and Cooper?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27315/49)

[What was Interstellar's post-climax scene all about?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27152/49)

[How can Cooper communicate with his daughter before the time he went to space?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27112/49)

[How was the data transferred across galaxies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27337/49)

[Why did it take a rocket to lift off the Earth but just shuttles to lift off the other planets?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27364/49)

[Was Gargantua not a "real" black hole?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27252/49)

[How is Cooper's age justified?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27257/49)

[Why Cooper or Dr. Brand can't send message?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27160/49)

[How can humans travel to 12 different planets in Interstellar?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27237/49)

[Spaceship to transport human in interstellar](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27361/49)

---

Judging by the amount of questions asked, one might want to call this challenge a success. But it also has to be taken into acount, that there would probably have been many questions about this newly-opened movie anyway and it stays questionable how much the challenge actually contributed in motivating those questions and how many people knew about it at all, let alone cared about it, especially when considering the recently low meta activity.

I guess in the future one might on the one hand rather chose more general or wider topics not tied to individual releases (or not about those releases alone) and on the other hand approach this whole thing from a more official side apart from a single user opening a challenge on a topic he deems fit, thus more like the good old [*Topic of the Week*](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/479/49). But this was more of a short-minded experiment anyway. I'll thus probably open a more general meta discussion properly asking the community for topic ideas and for more official backing from the site framework if possible.

Comment: What's the next topic, eh? Hunger Games Mockingjay?

Comment: @AndrewMartin Well, in this case probably *Hunger Games* in general. But I'm probably going to open a proper topic request post, as suggested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634). For now I guess topic of the week is the same as every week, ID-this-stuff. ;-)

Comment: I'd be up for some Hunger Games fun. Sounds like a good plan, I like :)