# Weekly Topic Challenge - Ideas

Tags: discussion, challenge

Quite a while ago we had a so called [*Topic of the Week*](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/479/49) where users were encouraged to ask questions about a specific topic and compete for the best question. In an effort to revive this kind of challenge, I'll try to follow [*Jon Ericson*'s excellent guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/162011) and would like to ask for topic ideas here.

The general procedure will be as follows:

1. Users propose some interesting ideas for topic challenges **as answers to this question** (one answer for one topic) and vote for the topics they like most.
2. Once we have a little stock of topics, we'll start a **weekly challenge for this topic, accompanied by a respective meta question**. *Jon* suggests a period from friday to friday, which sounds like a good idea, but maybe this can also be controlled on a topic by topic basis. Maybe one could even make it a two-week challenge, or only in specific cases. As to the technical problem of nomination, the topic will be bound to one or more specific tags. While *Jon* suggests a single tag for each challenge, I don't see any problem with multiple tags (e.g. for multiple movies of a series or director), this will prevent inappropriate agglomeration tags as happened with the last challenge.
3. Once the challenge is over, we can **list all the questions asked and the specific winners by question and answer votes** (hopefully the *Hot Network Questions* won't destroy the statistics completely ;-)). At the moment there aren't really any resources for actual material prizes, but well, for whatever reasons you're here, wealth isn't one of them anyway.
4. After the challenge we can **start a new one** from one of the other proposed topics, or we can **wait for a better moment, or for more topics**. Nobody says we have to force any single topic on the community every week (something that might have broken the motivation behind the last topic of the week, I guess).

**So what topics should we propose?**

It's really up to yourself what topic you like to have represented more, be this from specific movies, general broad topics, the entire works of a specific director, or something totally abstract we don't have any questions about at all. Here are just some small hints (with absolutely no obligation to be followed):

- Keep in mind that it should be broad enough to gather enough traction in a single week but also specific enough to not have every question asked attributed to it and maybe encourage questions to topics we might not already have much about.
- It could be a good idea to tie it to specific theatrical releases in order to profit from the natural temporal attraction of those releases. But in this case it might be good idea to not tie it to a single movie, whose questions will come anyway. Maybe try to broaden it, e.g. by asking about the whole franchise/series (where appropriate), or the the whole works of the director (if significant).
- Feel free to include ideas about the technicalities in your proposal, like what tags to count, when to best schedule the challenge, or if it maybe would be better served as a two-week challenge.

Comment: @NapoleanWilson Are any of these below proposed ideas ever see the light?

Comment: I would also like to know, are topic challenges still happening?

Comment: Well, sure they are. In fact there will soon be one. Any reason to believe they aren't?

Comment: I haven't seen challenges for a while... But maybe I was just not paying enough attention :)

Comment: @Luciano Well, there haven't been too many suggestions to begin with.

Answer (score 9):

## Spy Movies

**Undercover Operatives and Covert Ops of all kinds.**

There are several good series to choose from, including 26 *James Bond* films, 5 *Jason Bourne* films, and 5 *Jack Ryan* films.

There are also various standalone movies that would qualify, such as *Basic*, *Spy Game*, and *U-571*.

Answer (score 4):

In order to celebrate the [50th anniversary](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/in-pictures-37232329) of what [many people](http://www.sixofone.org.uk/) believe to be the greatest television series ever made:

[**The Prisoner**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061287/)

Still as relevant today as it was on its release, an allegory of modern bureaucracy and the struggle of the individual against the state.

A series to which there are multiple homages, notably whole episodes of StarTrek TNG that replicate Prisoner episodes and any number of scenes in Babylon 5.  Although The Prisoner itself is not Science Fiction.

*I am not a number, I am a free man!*

Comment: "*Although The Prisoner itself is not Science Fiction.*" - Depends on your definition of science fiction. Mind-altering drugs play a major role in many of the episodes. It's definitely [on-topic](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-prisoner) over at SFF.

Comment: *greatest television series ever made* is highly debatable bruv...

Comment: @Vishwa:  Of course it is, that's why it is a good topic.

Comment: @Chenmunka uh ha.. :D  lets do some of that action. seems interesting

Answer (score 2):

Since we're approaching the start of the Tokyo Olympic Games 2020(2021?) the theme could be

### Olympic Games

There are plenty of boxing movies, martial arts, basketball (Space Jam counts...), etc. A full list of the Olympic sports can be seen [here](https://olympics.com/en/sports/).