# Topic Challenge: Johnny Depp and his films

Tags: discussion, challenge

Last week saw the release of [*Mortdecai*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3045616/) with [*Johnny Depp*](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000136/?ref_=tt_cl_t1) in a seemingly typical role. So due to [popular opinion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1515/49) we're starting a new **weekly topic challenge from 2015-01-26 00:00 UTC to 2015-02-02 01:00 UTC** asking for any kind of question about ***Johnny Depp* and the films he was in**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners here. Also don't forget to [suggest new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [johnny-depp](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/johnny-depp) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Comment: Are people supposed to ask the questions here in META, or on the main site?

Comment: @DA. On the main site. It's a challenge for questions about a specific topic to drive activity on the main site. Meta is for meta questions, the main site is for on-topic questions. Look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/162011) for more general information on how topic challenges work.

Comment: What are the criteria of choosing the successful challenger?

Comment: @yondaime008 Votes. See [this related question](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for how topic challenges work in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge is over and the only and thus **top-voted question** (with a score of amazing -6 and ~70 views) was asked by [*Shiz Z.*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/763/shiz-z), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Is it important to Johnny Depp that he win a best-actor Oscar?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/30496/49)

Comment: very disappointing, its better to not have any then the worse receipt one.