# Oscar Topic Challenge Part II: The Academy Awards and their workings [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

The [87th Annual Academy Awards ("Oscars")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/87th_Academy_Awards) have just been held. This might be a chance to discuss the workings of the *Academy of Motion Picture Arts and Sciences* and the intricacies of choosing the year's best films and film-makers. So due to [popular opinion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1483/49) we're starting a new **weekly topic challenge. From 2015-02-23 00:00 UTC to 2015-03-02 01:00 UTC** we encourage you to ask any kind of on-topic<sup>1</sup> question on the main site about **the workings of the *Oscars*** (tagged with [academy-awards](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academy-awards)).

Once the challenge is over we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

1) <sub>Just be sure to not just plain ask why your favourite movie didn't win while it's so much better than any other. ;-)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge is over and the **top-voted question** (with a score of 23 and 6299 views) was asked by [*Tivep*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/16374), which makes him/her the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Why was The Lego Movie not nominated at the Oscars?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/31409/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Who chooses the host for the Oscar show?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/31591/49) (13 / ~763)