# Oscar 2016 Topic Challenge II: The Academy Awards and their workings [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

The [88th Annual Academy Awards ("Oscars")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/88th_Academy_Awards) have just been held. Like [last year](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1663/49) this might be a chance to discuss the workings of the *Academy of Motion Picture Arts and Sciences* and the intricacies of choosing the year's best films and film-makers. So due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2081/49) we're starting a new **weekly topic challenge. From 2016-02-29 00:00 UTC to 2016-03-06 01:00 UTC** we encourage you to ask any kind of on-topic<sup>1</sup> question on the main site about **the workings of the *Oscars*** (tagged with [academy-awards](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academy-awards)).

Once the challenge is over we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

1) <sub>Just be sure to not just plain ask why your favourite movie didn't win while it's so much better than any other. ;-)</sub>

Comment: [Winner](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49521/at-what-point-is-the-orchestra-told-who-the-academy-award-winner-will-be) seems quite clear this time, holly HNQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 45 and 4561 views) was asked by [*Thunderforge*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/12783), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [At what point is the orchestra told who the Academy Award winner will be?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/49521/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Has The Academy ever addressed the issue with acting categories being gender separated?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/49470/49) (10 / 124)
3. [Where does an Oscar winner go when they leave stage after accepting their award?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/49510/49) (8 / 204)
4. [Where do non-binary people fall for the gender specific awards in the Oscars?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/49566/49) (3 / 115)