# Oscar 2017 Topic Challenge II: The Academy Awards and their workings [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

The [89th Annual Academy Awards ("Oscars")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/89th_Academy_Awards) have just been held. Like [last year](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2171/49) this might be a chance to discuss the workings of the *Academy of Motion Picture Arts and Sciences* and the intricacies of choosing the year's best films and film-makers. So due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2607/49) we're starting a new **weekly topic challenge. From 2016-02-27 00:00 UTC to 2016-03-05 23:00 UTC** we encourage you to ask any kind of on-topic<sup>1</sup> question on the main site about **the workings of the *Oscars*** (tagged with [academy-awards](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academy-awards)).

Once the challenge is over we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

1) <sub>Just be sure to not just plain ask why your favourite movie didn't win while it's so much better than any other. ;-)</sub>

Comment: What kinds of questions about the workings of the Academy Awards *are* on topic here? The ["on-topic" help page](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) seems to indicate that only questions about *particular works* are on-topic. Even if a question about the Academy Awards is also about a particular movie, I don't really see how such a question would "add to the understanding or appreciation of the title" -- and the help page specifically lists such questions as being *off* topic.

Comment: @KyleStrand Where do you get from that "only questions about particular works are on-topic"? We have lots of question about general problems not necessarily pertaining to a specific work only, including about the workings of the film industry. You can take a look at the (unclosed) questions under the `academy-awards` tag for getting a feel of it.

Comment: From the "on-topic" page, as I said. The only text there indicating what *is* on topic is the first bullet list. Each of the items only seems applicable to a specific work or set of works: "content or theme", "a movie or TV show's production", "the works of a director..." etc, and identification questions.

Comment: Hmm, that might be a lack on the on-topic page, I guess. But well, that page has never been 100% complete and isn't really supposed to be. Anyway, questions about the film industry have usually gone well here.

Comment: Fair enough. I see why the community might want them to be on topic, and of course it's ultimately up to the community whether to allow them or not. I just find the guidelines for this site more confusing than those for other sites.

Comment: @KyleStrand If you have suggestions for improvements, perhaps you can raise them in another meta topic or discuss them in chat. If you're confused, others may be too, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Thunderforge Thanks; I have [done so](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2656/8411).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 43 and ~7,515 views) was asked by [*Darren*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/43889), which makes them the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Why aren't the front of Oscar winner envelopes marked with the award they're for?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/69366/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [At the Oscars, who decides where everyone sits?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/69306/49) (34 / ~3,984)
3. [Which members of the production crew are responsible for the envelopes containing Oscar winners?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/69287/49) (29 / ~4,349)
4. [What are the rules for eligibility to be included in the "In Memoriam" tribute during the Oscars?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/69284/49) (12 / ~1,007)
5. [Why isn't there an Oscar for TV Series, like with the Golden Globes?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/69363/49) (5 / ~2,151)

   [Why the disparities in number of nominations?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/69317/49) (5 / ~69)
6. [How many "Oscars" are given out per category](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/69351/49) (4 / ~69)
7. [How is a film chosen to be eligible for an Oscar?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/69316/49) (3 / ~79)

   [Why do some Oscar presenters present 2 awards?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/69407/49) (3 / ~29)