# Topic Challenge: Paul Walker and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

Last week saw the release of [*Furious 7*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2820852/), the newest installment in the *Fast & Furious* franchise and the last film featuring the late [*Paul Walker*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Walker). So we're starting a new **weekly topic challenge from 2015-04-06 00:00 UTC to 2015-04-12 23:00 UTC** asking for any kind of question about ***Paul Walker* and the films he starred in**.<sup>1</sup>

<sup>(The [original suggestion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1711/49) was about a *Fast & Furious* challenge. But given that this is definitely not the last big-franchise movie this year and that the interest into this movie doesn't seem so high yet, I thought it a better idea to broaden the scope a little, concentrating on the whole work of a late actor who has always enjoyed his role in that franchise.)</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [paul-walker](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paul-walker) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge is over and the only and thus **top-voted question** (with a score of amazing 0 and ~50 views) was asked by [*Tushar*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/13594), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [When did Letty regain her memories?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33132/49)

Comment: Pretty sure I made history winning with a score of zero!

Comment: @Tushar Oh, don't be too sure of that, you still have a long way down to go: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/a/1548/49. ;-)

Comment: A win at -6!!! You gotta be kidding me. Feeling almost proud of my zero :)