# Topic Challenge: The Marvel Cinematic Universe [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

This and the next week see the broad release of [*Avengers: Age of Ultron*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2395427/), the newest movie of the [*Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe), particularly their flagship movie putting together most of the characters from their various sub-series. This might be the right time to delve into all those various characters and their previous stories as well as the overarching continuity that holds them together. So due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1710/49) we're starting a new **biweekly topic challenge from 2015-04-25 00:00 UTC to 2015-05-08 23:00 UTC** asking for any kind of question about **any of the movies and TV-shows set in the *MCU* or about the *MCU* in general**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Comment: Excellent.  I'm going to have to avoid AoU questions for a week though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The challenge is over and the **top-voted question** (with a score of 18 and ~10114 views) was asked by [*Ankit Sharma*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Why was the Hulkbuster program called Veronica?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33734/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Is Captain America worthy of Mjolnir?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33875/49) (13 / ~723)
3. [What was Thor doing?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33975/49) (10 / ~149)
4. [How does Captain America reclaim his shield in The Winter Soldier?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33801/49) (9 / ~87)

   [What does Captain America mean by 'I have seen her (Black Widow) flirt upclose'?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33732/49) (9 / ~1212)
5. [How did Ultron come to be in the Sceptre?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33981/49) (8 / ~807)

   [Isn't the Quicksilver from Avengers 2 the same as the Quicksilver from X-Men: Days of Future Past?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33984/49) (8 / ~2485)

   [What happened to Jarvis at the end of Avengers: Age of Ultron](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33729/49) (8 / ~445)
6. [How was Age of Ultron's post-credit scene even possible?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33884/49) (7 / ~293)
7. [Is Captain America captain of the Avengers team?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33791/49) (6 / ~240)
8. [Why was this specific character in Age Of Ultron killed off?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33893/49) (5 / ~178)

   [Why no Marvel One-Shot for The Winter Soldier?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33833/49) (5 / ~766)

   [Did Thanos have anything to do with the events of Age of Ultron?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33792/49) (5 / ~251)

   [Regarding Age of Ultron's post-credit scene](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33770/49) (5 / ~256)

   [What makes Ultron the person he is?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33751/49) (5 / ~240)

   [What is the reason for Hulk's decision at the end?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33690/49) (5 / ~909)
9. [What do we know about Strucker?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33976/49) (4 / ~76)

   [What were the other A.I. chips and whom are they referring to?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33907/49) (4 / 133)

   [Are there any details about the contract that Aaron Taylor-Johnson signed to be a part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33763/49) (4 / ~6539)

   [Why did Hawkeye become immune to mind control effects?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34101/49) (4 / ~343)
10. [Why is Daredevil 2015 so brutal?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33994/49) (3 / ~48)

    [Can Quicksilver push bullets out of the way?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33950/49) (3 / ~188)

    [What is the time-frame of the 1st season of Daredevil?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33740/49) (3 / ~58)

    [How did Tony Stark get his new suits?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33727/49) (3 / ~436)
11. [Why didn't he get the power of Mjolnir?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33689/49) (2 / ~367)

    [How did Variety know how many families went to see "Avengers: Age of Ultron"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34007/49) (2 / ~200)
12. [How does Iron Man's costume serve to emphasize the aspects of his character?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33794/49) (0 / ~86)