# Topic Challenge: Movies/TV-shows with post-apocalyptic settings [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

Last week saw the release of [*Mad Max: Fury Road*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1392190/), continuing the *Mad Max* series after 30 years. So we're starting a new **weekly topic challenge from 2015-05-18 00:00 UTC to 2015-05-24 23:00 UTC** asking for any kind of question about **any movie or TV-show set in a post-apocalyptic environment**.

<sup>(The [original suggestion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1790/49) was about a *Mad Max* challenge. But given that this is definitely not the last big-franchise movie this year, I thought it a better idea to broaden the scope a little, concentrating on a whole genre/setting which that particular series has been quite influential in. The topic might be a bit broad and fuzzy, but I'm sure we can get the corresponding questions sorted out reasonably easily.)</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the **top-voted question** (with a score of 6 and ~6230 views) was asked by [*tedder42*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/9685), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [What was the silver "valhalla spray" in Fury Road?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34474/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Why sudden change in war boy's motives?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34498/49) (5 / ~153)
3. [What's the relation between the different clans?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34527/49) (4 / ~59)

   [Significance of the Crows in Mad Max: Fury Road](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34601/49) (4 / ~631)
4. [What all was on Max's back?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34496/49) (3 / ~105)
5. [What liquid was being carried in the tanker?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34476/49) (2 / ~153)
6. [Who are the Many Mothers in Mad Max: Fury Road?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34600/49) (0 / ~134)