# Topic Challenge: Original stand-alone movies [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

This year sees the continuation of various established movie franchises, along with many other book and comic adaptations. This way it is continuing a [modern trend](https://static.shortoftheweek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Loss-of-Originality-STATS8.gif) of rebooting/remaking, sequeling/prequeling and adapting existing works. As a sort of counter-measure we'd thus like to start a challenge not concentrating on the works of a particular actor/director/franchise, but on purely original stand-alone movies. So due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1715/49) we're starting a new **(almost) biweekly topic challenge from 2015-05-26 12:00 UTC to 2015-06-07 12:00 UTC** asking for any kind of question about **any movie that does not have any direct sequels/prequels/spin-offs/..., is not part of some larger franchise, and was not remade or adapted from anything**, purely original stand-alone movies that is.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Comment: ... I don't believe these exist. :P

Comment: Sure they do. The Matrix, Raiders of the Lost Arc... There area bunch of such movies where one shudders to think of what a sequel would have been like.

Comment: Ahem, _The Matrix_ had 2 sequels, and _Raiders of the Lost Ark_ had 3. Not all of them were as good as the first one, of course.

Comment: @zoagli I'm pretty sure that was the point, and that James McLeod's comment was a joke about the sequels being inferior.

Comment: 1) Do movies such as *Avatar* for which an unreleased sequel is in the works count? 2) Is there somewhere we can list suggested movies as topics? 3) Do movies based (or loosely based) on real events (such as *Titanic*) count?

Comment: @KyleStrand 1) Don't know for sure, but I guess yes. 2) What do you mean? I can't follow. 3) Don't know for sure, depends I guess. The problem with Titanic isn't that it's based on reality (afterall it isn't really an adaptation of any other work), but rather that it already has been done a million times. But that's a problem to be solved once a question about that movie is asked at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the **top-voted question** (with a score of 7 and ~77 views) was asked by [*CPU Terminator*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/21614), which makes him/her the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [A possible Donnie Darko reference to 2002](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34853/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [How can a mechanic tell if sugar was added to the fuel tank?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34825/49) (6 / ~1295)
3. [How did Ava get on the helicopter?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35081/49) (3 / ~59)
4. [How can the A.I. robot charge its battery?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34776/49) (2 / ~140)

   [Ending of Eden Lake](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34868/49) (2 / ~39)
5. [Why was Mal's projection in limbo?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34826/49) (1 / ~73)

   [Force Majeure (2014): significance of scene in the fog](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34911/49) (1 / ~17)

   https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35052/49 (1 / ~22)

   [Why is the Beatles music appropriate in American Beauty?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35156/49) (1 / ~12)
6. [sun setting in the south](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34887/49) (0 / ~62)

Comment: Do I get an award?

Comment: @CPUTerminator No, only the honour of winning. ;-)

Comment: Donnie Darko has a direct sequel, though...??

Comment: @KyleStrand But it's not part of some kind of larger-scale planned franchise. The sequel was never intended with the slight of a thought when the movie was made.

Comment: The part in bold in your original question phrases the restriction as "does not have any direct sequels", though. I think I understand the intent now, but that certainly wasn't clear from the original challenge phrasing.

Comment: @KyleStrand Sure, the whole challenge was pretty unclear and fuzzy. I rather chose to err on the side of including too much, though.

Comment: Fair enough. Also, for most films that initiated franchises (including Star Wars and The Matrix), the filmmakers had no guarantee that the film would be successful enough for the studio to fund a sequel.