# Topic Challenge: Christopher Lee and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

Last sunday saw the death of [*Christopher Lee*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Lee), who counts to his many achievements being a successful and renowned actor for nearly 70 years. So to honor him we decided to start a **weekly topic challenge from 2015-06-15 00:00 UTC to 2015-06-21 23:00 UTC** asking for any kind of question about **Christopher Lee and the films he was in**.<sup>1</sup>

<sup>(Sorry if this was not proposed and voted upon through the official topic suggestion thread. It was a rather short-term idea I had just tonight and since we still have some room in the time schedule right now, I thought to cram it in. But I asked in chat if people would think it an interesting idea, which they did. Just vote this down if you think it to be an awful idea.)</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [christopher-lee](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christopher-lee) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Comment: Just to clarify... if someone asks a question that just happens to be about Lee but doesn't necessarily refer to his character, does that still count?

Comment: @Catija Uh what? You mean a question that happens to be about him but isn't about him? Didn't get that. That being said, *"any kind of question about Christopher Lee and the films he was in"*, so any question about him or any movie he starred in counts, it's difficult to keep track otherwise. But of course, it goes without saying that the question has to be on-topic in the first place. If someone asks what Christopher Lee did in his WWII time, that would be as off-topic as always. If you ask about his particular traits/methods as an actor, then that seems an on-topic question.

Comment: Mostly I was meaning something along the lines of... if a question is specifically about Gollum in *LotR* would it still count... Yes, it's technically a film that has Lee in it but it's not about his character.

Comment: Great topic! I would hope this would get tons of questions, as his works are so plentiful, it should make it easy ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is over and the winner is [*Shrilekha*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/21342) with his excellent question about Saruman's motivation (garnering a score of 4 and ~77 views):

## 1. [What was Saruman's motivation in the Lord of the Rings trilogy?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35514/49)

There was one other question asked about a Christopher Lee movie, yet less about him or his role but a more general one, which garnered a score of 1 for 83 views:

2. [Contradictions in Star Wars about advocating pacifism?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35542/49)

Comment: Interesting answers i got. Appreciate the help everyone.   R.i.p Chris Lee, he will keep living through his work.

Answer (score 9):

Great idea! When a topic suddenly become especially timely — like the passing of an icon who mastered so many roles — it is especially touching and engaging to reach out to the folks who likely have lots of questions. And since you're not the only one having these questions, this is a great way to to invite the folks who are searching the Internet for this information to find the answers you write here.

So when you're asking and answer these questions, do everything you can to really kill it. Don't just answer with a hyperlink to some other discussion group somewhere. This is a great opportunity to build up a body of answers to a challenge that everyone is particularly interested in right now. And if you continue to have great answers like we have in the past, you stand a good chance of attracting some great new users who will add value for years to come.

Rest in peace, Mr. Lee. You are truly a legend. We'll miss you.