# Topic Challenge: Tom Cruise and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

This and the next week see the broad release of [*Mission: Impossible - Rogue Nation*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2381249/), the 5th installment in a movie series largely known for and carried by [Tom Cruise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Cruise). So due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1862/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge from 2015-08-01 00:00 UTC to 2015-08-10 23:00 UTC** asking for any kind of question about **Tom Cruise and the films he was in**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [tom-cruise](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tom-cruise) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Comment: Tom I think you should add a [tag:status-completed] instead of writing that in the title.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M I thought about this, too (though, quite some time ago admittedly). But I thought having it in the title would be a bit more clear, as it could be a bit confusing to read that there's a topic challenge when there actually isn't. I agree that the tag would convey the same message, but I somehow thought it's not as clear as a title change, seeing that it really is a one-time event. Especially when those questions happen to appear in the Hot Meta Questions side bar after the challenge is over. Maybe I was also influenced the other SE sites, which also change the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the **top-voted question** (with a score of 3 and ~59 views) was asked by [*Basim Rauf*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/21338), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Question about Jim and Claire's relationship](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/37328/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [About the events in Morocco?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/37412/49) (2 / ~55)
3. [Question about Final Scenes in Mission: Impossible - Rogue Nation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/37557/49) (1 / ~29)