# Topic Challenge: Biographical Dramas [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

With the release of [*Pawn Sacrifice*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1596345/) and due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1820/49) we're starting a new **weekly topic challenge from 2015-09-21 00:00 UTC to 2015-09-27 23:00 UTC** asking for any kind of question about **biographical dramas**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Comment: just curios, How do you identify if a question is related to Biographical Drama. There is no tag for it and don't think you will go through each and every question to identify.

Comment: @HBhatia *"don't think you will go through each and every question"* - Uh, that's exactly what I always do for each and every challenge, tag or not. Since we get ~150 questions a week this isn't really that unfeasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge is over and the **top-voted question** (with a score of 3 and ~47 views) was asked by [*Shaloni Sharma*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/26201), which makes them the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Are there any sequel movies based on true story?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/41556/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Why does the movie Pawn Sacrifice claim that game 6 was the greatest game of chess ever played?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/41568/49) (2 / ~26)
3. [Why did Brian Halloran go to the FBI in Black Mass?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/41420/49) (1 / ~26)