# Topic Challenge: Lone survival movies [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

With the release of [*The Martian*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3659388/) and due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1949/49) we're starting a new **weekly topic challenge from 2015-10-03 00:00 UTC to 2015-10-11 23:00 UTC** asking for any kind of question about **films that are about surviving alone, regardless of the circumstances**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Comment: Is there any special tag we need to add to the question as its not clear about how you will differentiate questions

Comment: @war_Hero No, there isn't. How I will differentiate it? Well, to the best of my knowledge and the help of Wikipedia/IMDb, I'm afraid. With the few questions we'll actually get that's largely managable without problems. Any borderline cases can be treated *if* they arise and there's always possibility to be a bit more lenient and inclusive in such cases.

Comment: Well we can ask the moderator to create a tag for these challenges

Comment: @war_Hero Uh, no (well, of course you can *ask*, though). I think that's a *very* bad idea, since it will dillute the page with temporary meta tags and especially since not everyone who asks an eligible question might be aware of the tag at all (let alone the actual challenge). And who removes those things afterwards? In most of the cases the challenge is pretty much tied to one or more specific tags and if it isn't, a tag that isn't used 100% consistently won't solve the problem either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is over and the **top-voted question** (with a score of 5 and ~1027 views) was asked by [*hitman4890*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/18957), which makes them the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Where did Mark Watney get the escape pod in The Martian?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/41924/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Is there any purpose to the short fade to white?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/42070/49) (4 / ~41)
3. [How detrimental was the initial hull breach by the shipping container for the boat's ultimate fate?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/41965/49) (2 / ~17)

   [Extra oxygen from breathing when lighting up the hydrazine?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/41845/49) (2 / ~141)
4. [How did they survive the way back?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/42113/49) (1 / ~25)
5. [Why couldnt the crew land on mars to pick Mark Watney up?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/41980/49) (0 / ~129)