# Topic Challenge: Time travel in movies and TV [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

With the celebration of "Back to the Future Day" on October the 21st 2015 (the day Marty and Doc traveled to in [*Back to the Future 2*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096874/)) and due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1960/49) we're starting a new **weekly topic challenge from 2015-10-21 00:00 UTC to 2015-10-28 23:00 UTC** asking for **questions about the intricacies of time travel in movies and TV-shows**. From plot-explanations of weird paradoxa in specific movies to general questions regarding the variants for depicting time travel on the screen.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

1) <sub>This might be a rather fuzzy definition of the topic and might thus come with difficulties in assessing the eligible questions, especially since we shouldn't really encourage an over-abundant usage of the [time-travel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-travel) tag. But I guess with some reasonable thought put into it and a little leniency, it shouldn't be too difficult to sort out what questions really concentrate on problems inherent to time travel and what are unrelated plot explanation questions.</sub>

Comment: I have a time travel question I'd been planning on asking in Science Fiction & Fantasy. I'm new to both communities, but since time travel is inherently a science fiction device, I'm probably not the only one with this question: I assume that most of these questions would normally go on the other site, but are okay during this challenge. Is that correct?

Comment: @Josh It is entirely up to you where you ask the question. They would *not* normally be moved over there as long as they are on-topic here. No on-topic question is ever going to be migrated, disregarding any challenges running. In general, on-topic questions are *always* ok and challenges won't ever change that. On the other hand if the question is off-topic in the first place, the challenge won't change that either. A challenge does always come with the implied requirement that the question has to be on-topic on the site. So the decision is entirely up to you if it is on-topic on both sites.

Comment: @Josh For more information on the matter, take a look at this related general question: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2/49, as well as this one for some possible guidance on making a decision: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/376/49.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge and the only and thus **top-voted question** (with a score of 4 and ~40 views) was asked by [*Josh*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/27012), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Track all changes to the timeline in the Terminator series](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/42592/49)

<sup>(In retrospect it might have been better to open the challenge towards *any* kind of question about movies/TV-shows featuring time-travel, since there were some really good ones, some even motivated by the challenge itself. But alas, this wasn't done, you can blame that on me as a wrong decision.)</sup>