# Topic Challenge: James Bond and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

With the release of [*Spectre*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2379713/) as the 24th installment in the EON-produced [*James Bond*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Bond_in_film) film series and due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1836/49) we're starting a new **biweekly topic challenge from 2015-10-31 00:00 UTC to 2015-11-13 23:00 UTC** asking for any kind of question about ***James Bond* and the films he appeared in** (neatly trackable with the [james-bond](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/james-bond) tag).

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is over and the **top-voted question** (with a score of 6 and ~175 views) was asked by [*Mason Wheeler*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/2023), which makes them the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [What is Bond's first line in Spectre?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/43126/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Significance of the painting behind M in the restaurant](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/43322/49) (4 / ~71)

   [How was pre-title opening in Spectre shot?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/43199/49) (4 / ~177)
3. [Why wasn't Teresa Bond's tombstone written as Tracy Bond?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/43358/49) (2 / ~30)

   [Is there any criteria for selection of James bond?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/43308/49) (2 / ~111)

   [Is Franz Oberhauser related to the original Blofeld?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/42959/49) (2 / ~207)