# Topic Challenge: The Hunger Games [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

Last week saw the release of [*The Hunger Games: Mockingjay - Part 2*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1951266/), the conclusion of the [*Hunger Games* series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hunger_Games_%28film_series%29). So due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1934/49) we're starting a **topic challenge from 2015-11-25 00:00 UTC to 2015-12-06 23:00 UTC** asking for any kind of question about **the *Hunger Games* movies** (conveniently taggable with [the-hunger-games](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hunger-games)).

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

May the odds be ever in your favor!

Comment: But the odds are never in our favor...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the **top-voted question** (with a score of 6 and ~131 views) was asked by [*cde*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/23541), which makes them the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [What changes to Mockingjay Part 2 were made due to P. S. Hoffman's passing?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44151/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Why do the movie posters show Katniss in red?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/43962/49) (5 / ~306)
3. [Does the rest of the world know what's happening in Panem (do they even care)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44163/49) (4 / ~102)

   [Was Snow turning senile?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44144/49) (4 / ~41)
4. [What was being referred to in the Mockingjay Part 2 Epilogue?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/43961/49) (2 / ~205)

   [Who are the office workers in Panem?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44217/49) (2 / ~130)
5. [Why have static targets for tributes while demoing their skills?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44138/49) (1 / ~49)
6. [Do Panem citizens know of their Roman namesake?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44146/49) (-1 / ~35)