# Topic Challenge: Star Wars [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

With the release of the long-awaited continuation of the [*Star Wars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars) saga in [*Star Wars: The Force Awakens*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/) and due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1973/49) we're ending this year with a bang. **From 2015-12-18 00:00 UTC to 2015-12-31 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great **questions about anything *Star Wars*** (conveniently taggable with [star-wars](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars)).<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

*May the force be with you!*

---

1) <sub>This is actually a general policy here to be followed for every question, but seeing how this film is a rather big thing on the internet and people can react quite sensitive to spoilers, we would once again remind everyone that **spoilers in question titles are to be strictly avoided**. If you see a spoiler in someone else's question titles, feel free to edit it out or bring it to attention so it can be fixed as fast as possible.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge is over and the **top-voted question** (with a score of 17 and ~4068 views) was asked by [*hitman4890*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/18957), which makes them the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Age difference between Anakin Skywalker and Padmé in the Star Wars prequel trilogy](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45223/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Does Rey speak Shyriiwook?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45184/49) (16 / ~1998)
3. [Was the famous “Wilhelm Scream” used in “The Force Awakens?”](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45161/49) (12 / ~614)
4. [Why was the Force Ghost scene altered in the 2004 DVD version of Return of the Jedi?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45522/49) (11 / ~2264)
5. [Who is Rey’s family?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44936/49) (10 / ~1034)

   [What prompted R2-D2 to wake up at this point in “The Force Awakens?”](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45054/49) (10 / ~3108)
6. [Who is the father of Darth Vader?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45505/49) (9 / ~177)

   [How can Maz have Luke's lightsaber in Star Wars VII?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45132/49) (9 / ~241)
7. [What language does BB-8 speak?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45579/49) (8 / ~1156)
8. [Why does The Force Awakens not use the Episode notation?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45028/49) (7 / ~286)

   [Why do Obi-Wan and Anakin not get burned during their battle on the lava?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45228/49) (7 / ~1775)

   [How did Darth Vader learn Luke was his son?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44984/49) (7 / ~270)

   [Which is the correct pronunciation of Han in Star Wars?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45116/49) (7 / ~1374)

   [Why did Obi-Wan vanish after his fight with Vader?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45286/49) (7 / ~150)

   [Who is Lor San Tekka?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44963/49) (7 / ~14099)
9. [What is the right age for starting a training for Jedi?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45506/49) (6 / ~1152)

   [How did the Resistance know their planet was the next target?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44934/49) (6 / ~189)
10. [Who is Supreme Leader Snoke?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44937/49) (5 / ~537)

    [How did Supreme Leader Snoke seduce him to the Dark Side?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44938/49) (5 / ~534)

    [If the Jedi way is to avoid aggression and only fight as a form of defense, then how come every battle starts with the good guys attacking first?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45540/49) (5 / ~121)
11. [Why was Kylo Ren punching himself?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45049/49) (4 / ~2600)

    [Why does the First Order in “The Force Awakens” refer to the Resistance as “Rebels” when the Republic is reinstated?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44968/49) (4 / ~284)
12. [Was the twist in The Empire Strikes Back leaked to the public before the movie's release?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44930/49) (3 / ~75)

    [Who is the chosen one?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45318/49) (3 / ~65)

    [How did Kylo Ren get ahead of them?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45050/49) (3 / ~197)

    [Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith vs. The Clone Wars](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45229/49) (3 / ~73)

    [Is there some term for the English used by Yoda?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45439/49) (3 / ~76)

    [What are the subplots common to both The Force Awakens and A New Hope?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45001/49) (3 / ~252)
13. [Why did Kylo Ren take such a drastic action?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45084/49) (2 / ~853)

    [Question regarding Kylo Ren line](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44931/49) (2 / ~539)

    [Confused about the Resistance base in The Force Awakens](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44961/49) (2 / ~748)

    [What did Kylo mean by he has to do something difficult?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44935/49) (2 / ~507)
14. [Why does master Qui-Gon think Anakin is the "chosen one" while others do not?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45222/49) (1 / ~113)

    [What is the in-universe significance of different colours of lightsabers in Star Wars?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45441/49) (1 / ~82)
15. [How are Lightsabers created in Star Wars?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45500/49) (0 / ~54)
16. [How does Han communicate with Chewbacca?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45182/49) (-3 / ~163)

Comment: Ahhh, still on 4th place with a late entry