# Topic Challenge: Alan Rickman and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

Last week saw the death of renowned actor [*Alan Rickman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Rickman). So to honor him and due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2088/49) we'll start a **weekly topic challenge from 2016-01-18 00:00 UTC to 2016-01-24 23:00 UTC** asking for any kind of question about **Alan Rickman and the films he was in**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add an [alan-rickman](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alan-rickman) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge is over and it garned a few questions. Not all of them are about Alan Rickman's characters specifically, but the challenge asked for any kind of question about his films anyway. So the winner is [*dounyy*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/28388)'s question about one of the *Harry Potter* films, with a score of 11 and ~2820 views:

## 1. [Why did the magic ceiling not react to professor Quirrell?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/46500/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Did Harry and Mia actually have sex?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/46633/49) (8 / ~65)
3. [Would Theo face the death penalty post-Die Hard?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/46477/49) (4 / ~65)

Comment: Glad to know I won a challenge I was not even aware of \o/
I would like to thank my wife for supporting me.

Comment: That is some juxtaposition of question titles! 2 related to Harry Potter and then a 3rd asking if Harry and someone actually had sex!