# Topic Challenge: The X-Files [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

With the release of the long-awaited new revived season of [*The X-Files*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4370492/) and due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2031/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge from 2016-01-25 00:00 UTC to 2016-01-31 23:00 UTC** asking for any kind of question about the **TV-shows and films belonging to the [*X-Files* universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_X-Files_%28franchise%29).**<sup>1)</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

1) <sub>In particular this would be the original *X-Files* TV-show as well as its revival, of course, the two movies from 1998 and 2008 respectively, as well as the two spin-offs *The Lone Gunmen* and *Millennium*. While the latter is only very marginally related to the *X-Files*, it's still set in the same continuity and we're including it for the sake of completeness.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 7 and ~85 views) was asked by [*Dpeif*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/7536), which makes them the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Old Man's interaction with Mulder "10 years ago"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/46737/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Does X-Files (2016) follow last season of X-Files (2002) story-wise?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/46802/49) (6 / ~289)
3. [Are the Clean Shaven Officer and the Old Man supposed to be the same person?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/46719/49) (3 / ~62)
4. [What is the significance of the ape movies in X-Files S10E02: Founder's Mutation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/46821/49) (1 / ~49)

Comment: I'm honored and vindicated, thank you all