# Topic Challenge: TV-shows inspired by films [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

In the modern age of TV it has become quite a habit to adapt films into TV-shows, from *Bates Motel*, over *Fargo*, to *Stargate SG-1* (see [Wikipedia for a more extensive list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_television_programs_based_on_films)). So due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1974/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge from 2016-02-13 00:00 UTC to 2016-02-21 23:00 UTC** asking for any kind of question about **TV-shows inspired by feature films**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Comment: First time participating in a topic challenge. Are we supposed to call out questions that were created in response to this challenge? I just asked [Does time travel in the 12 Monkeys TV show work differently than in the movie?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/48848/12783)

Comment: @Thunderforge No, just ask your questions as you always do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted questions (with a score of 5 and 61/53/52 views respectively) were asked by [*Thunderforge*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/12783) and [*DarkElf73*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/31360), which makes them the winners of this challenge:

## 1. [Is Indy's line about Pancho Villa a reference to The Young Indiana Jones Chronicles?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/49101/49)

## [Does time travel in the 12 Monkeys TV show work differently than in the movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/48848/49)

## [Is Senator Morra on NZT or not?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/49009/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Did Oscar's date deceive Emily in an episode of The Odd Couple?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/48873/49) (3 / ~28)

Comment: Does winning just mean bragging rights?

Comment: @Thunderforge Indeed it does. For more information see the [introductory post on topic challenges](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49).