# Topic Challenge: Movies/TV-shows set in ancient Rome [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

Celebrating the foundation of Rome on April 21st and due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2184/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge from 2016-04-18 00:00 UTC to 2016-04-24 23:00 UTC** asking for any kind of question about **the various movies and TV-shows set in ancient Rome**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 6 and ~29 views) was asked by [*rand al'thor*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/27759), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Roman Mysteries: differences between books and TV adaptation?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52027/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Were gladiators forced to fight in historical reenactments, as they did in "Gladiator"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52032/49) (2 / 68)