# Topic Challenge: Game of Thrones [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

With the start of the 6th season of *Game of Thrones* and due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2220/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2016-04-25 00:00 UTC to 2016-05-06 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great **questions about anything *Game of Thrones*** (conveniently taggable with [game-of-thrones](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones)).

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Comment: I am new to SE. May I know what prize would you give to the winners? Reputation bounty?

Comment: @SiddharthVenu "Just" the honour. For more information take a look at the [introductory post on topic challenges](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49).

Comment: @SiddharthVenu On the side note, question can't be awarded with Reputation bounty. Only answers gets Reputation bounty.

Comment: @SiddharthVenu If you play the Game of Thrones Topic Challenge, you win or you die.

Comment: But if you try to win, you will get stabbed :P

Comment: You might get stabbed anyway. Poor "a character".

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Not even a badge? :-) Thanks though; I didn't even know this was a thing till I got the prize!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 20 and ~379 views) was asked by [*Jayraj*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/6793), which makes them the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Why is the dialogue in Game of Thrones more "modern"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52314/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [What is this wax seal used by Eddard Stark in "You Win or You Die"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52232/49) (19 / ~3715)
3. [How Did Obara Sand manage this?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52202/49) (14 / ~737)
4. [Why did Tommen stop Cersei from attending the funeral?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52472/49) (10 / ~2835)

   [Does Davos in season 6 know what happened to Shireen in season 5?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52458/49) (10 / ~1878)
5. [Why did Melisandre appear like this in S06E01?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52246/49) (9 / ~827)

   [Loophole in the Night's Watch oath?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52497/49) (9 / ~546)

   [Purpose of Davos protecting Jon Snow?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52308/49) (9 / ~487)
6. [Why did no one help Arya?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52278/49) (8 / ~320)

   [What happened to the dogs when Brienne came?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52198/49) (8 / ~1695)

   [Balon Greyjoy's assessment of the War of the Five Kings](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52469/49) (8 / ~203)
7. [Why does Ser Davos stare at the blood stain?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52604/49) (7 / ~114)
8. [Why does Davos care about Jon so much?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52634/49) (5 / ~120)
9. [Did the Waif possibly turn into Jaqen after attacking Arya?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52491/49) (3 / ~261)

   [Why was Hodor renamed in the TV show?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52629/49) (3 / ~98)
10. [Where exactly was Trystane Martell in "Red Woman"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52562/49) (2 / ~125)

    [Did Maester Luwin really believe that sorcery and magic is no more?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52682/49) (2 / ~33)
11. [How did they survive the jump?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52622/49) (1 / ~85)

Comment: My ranking is better on the basis of view count ;) Holly HNQ :D