# Topic Challenge: William Shakespeare [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

This year celebrates the 400th anniversary of the death of [William Shakespeare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Shakespeare), who has significantly shaped English literature and, being the famous and appreciated playwright he was, provided the base for various film and TV adaptations. So in honour of him and due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2241/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2016-06-14 00:00 UTC to 2016-06-24 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great **questions about films and TV-shows based on William Shakespeare and his works**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible

Comment: To make it clear, we are not sticking with Hollywood only?

Comment: Why would we? That's not Hollywood.SE, not at all.

Comment: fair enough....

Comment: Presumably the plays themselves are off-topic here?

Comment: @randal'thor Yes, of course, unless they have been adapted to screen, as written in the question. Which doesn't mean you can't ask about explanations of plot and characters from the specific adapations, no matter if those explanations come from the source material. A play is in itself a quite movie-friendly form of literature (and what is a movie if not a "more elaborately decorated theatre play" and thus an extension of classic drama). So it's natural that explanations of a film's dialogue and themes might have to be sought in the play it was based on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 11 and ~872) was asked by [*cde*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/23541), which makes them the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Why does Chancellor Gorkon think Shakespeare was Klingon?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/55614/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [What does the ending of 2015's Macbeth mean?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/55556/49) (5 / ~119)

   [How does the Macbeths' child add to their characterization and does it have a precedent?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/55569/49) (5 / ~85)
3. [What plays are the Shakespeare quotes in Star Trek VI from?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/55633/49) (4 / ~69)

   [Did Vishal Bhardwaj want to make Shakespearean trilogy from the start?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/55681/49) (4 / ~56)
4. [Was Roohdaar intended to be the replacement of Hamlet's father's ghost?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/55913/49) (3 / ~20)

   [Why did Vishal Bhardwaj avoid supernatural themes in Haider and Maqbool?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/55889/49) (3 / ~18)
5. [Why did the 1996 version of Hamlet include Robin Williams and other high-profile actors in minor roles?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/55724/49) (1 / ~39)

   [To which degree do dubbed versions of Shakespeare adaptations consult existing official translations?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/55758/49) (1 / ~27)

<sub>While some of them might not technically have been about films and TV-shows based on William Shakespeare and his works directly, they were still specifically about Shakespeare's treatment and significance in the respective films. So we just decided to add them, since it can't hurt to be a little more inclusive with those fun challenges.</sub>