# Topic Challenge: Movies and TV-shows with animals as primary characters [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

The 5th of July 2016 celebrated the 55.5th anniversary of [*Mister Ed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mister_Ed). So in honour of it and due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2020/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2016-07-05 00:00 UTC to 2016-07-15 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great **questions about films and TV-shows featuring an animal as primary character**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible

Comment: ... does this exclude films where the entire cast is animals, like *Zootopia*?

Comment: @Catija I would think it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 5 and ~173) was asked by [*steelershark*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22792), which makes her the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Why did filmmakers choose the particular dog breeds that are showcased?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/56547/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Did The Littlest Hobo ever find a happy home?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/56485/49) (4 / ~44)

   [Why are goats used as a symbol for yoga/meditation?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/56769/49) (4 / ~44)

   [How does Marlin know Jenny and Charlie in Finding Dory](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/56663/49) (4 / ~64)
3. [Why does Ice Bear talk in the third person?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/56648/49) (3 / ~28)
4. [Why did Kai believe that Oogway betrayed him in Kung Fu Panda 3?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/56478/49) (2 / ~94)
5. [How did team 1 of animals find team 2 of animals?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/56640/49) (1 / ~24)