# Topic Challenge: 50 years of Star Trek [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

In addition to the broad release of [*Star Trek Beyond*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2660888/), the 13th installment in the official *Star Trek* movie series, this year also celebrates the 50th anniversary of the [*Star Trek* franchise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek), one of the biggest and most famous film and TV franchises, and science-fiction universes in general, to date. So in order to celebrate the various films and TV shows this universe has generated over the years and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2185/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2016-07-23 00:00 UTC to 2016-08-05 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great **questions about anything *Star Trek*** (conveniently taggable with [star-trek](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek)).

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Comment: Oops I just missed it by one day. http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/57095/27264

Comment: "…for our next possible" Next possible what? The next possible cliffhanger? Oh, come on. Even on Meta now? :D

Comment: @Mario Gheez, couldn't you have told me that about 3 challenges ago before I copied the exact same text to all the following questions? ;-)

Comment: I love cliffhangers ;) I think this [twist is about sports](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/a/2368/1190)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 68 and ~12489) was asked by [*Thunderforge*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/12783), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Was Kirk and Uhura's kiss in Star Trek really the first interracial kiss on TV?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/57324/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [What was the device named by fans of Star Trek?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/57220/49) (8 / ~136)
3. [Why didn't Krall know about the Franklin?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/57233/49) (7 / ~304)
4. [How could this jump in ranks be possible?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/57497/49) (6 / ~100)
5. [If the Star Trek TNG future has no money, were there any stakes to the poker games the officers played?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/57449/49) (5 / ~66)

   [Was the Starfleet officer connected to the later series?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/57212/49) (5 / ~82)

   [How does the USS Franklin fit in the pre-Kelvin Timeline?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/57164/49) (5 / ~1018)
6. [What was the ship under construction initially called?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/57211/49) (3 / ~121)
7. [Distance between Yorktown and the unexplored planet](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/57690/49) (2 / ~47)

   [In Wrath of Khan, what is the meaning of "the word is given" in the scene where the crewman dies in sickbay?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/57448/49) (2 / ~76)

   [Who were the faceless mooks?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/57166/49) (2 / ~127)

   [What happened to the the USS Franklin crew?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/57252/49) (2 / ~173)
8. [Sulu's Daughter's Parentage?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/57165/49) (0 / ~68)