# 33rd Question Olympics: Sports movies [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

In honour of the [*2016 Summer Olympics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Summer_Olympics) running from August 5th-21st and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2368/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge**, the 33rd since the modern reinvention of topic challenges. **From 2016-08-06 00:00 UTC to 2016-08-21 23:00 UTC we're challenging you to all your great questions about sports movies** be they Olympics-based or not.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

And don't forget that the most important thing is not to win but to take part!

Comment: Title is bit confusing

Comment: @AnkitSharma Why? Do you know what Olympics are?

Comment: I know but  "33rd Question Olympics" sounds bit weird

Comment: @AnkitSharma How?

Comment: Worth noting that questions regarding [movies about the Olympic Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Films_about_the_Olympic_Games) are encouraged, but any sports movies are acceptable for this topic challenge.

Comment: @AnkitSharma I am agree with you. Title is bit confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Olympics are over and the **gold** medal goes to [*Thunderforge*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/12783) for a score of 5 and ~593 views:

## 1. [Are there any ice hockey movies where the team loses the big game?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/59288/49)

The **silver** medal goes to [*steelerfan*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22792) for a score of 4 and ~148 views:

### 2. [Why weren't actual NFL teams used?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/58824/49)

And the **bronze** medal goes to [*Thunderforge*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/12783) again for a score of 1 and ~42 views:

#### 3. [In the script of a team sports movie, how much detail is there about what a specific play looks like?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/59290/49)