# Topic Challenge: Gene Wilder and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

August 29th saw the death of renowned actor [*Gene Wilder*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_Wilder). So in honour of him and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2399/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2016-09-05 00:00 UTC to 2016-09-11 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **Gene Wilder and the films he was in**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [gene-wilder](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gene-wilder) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 22 and ~1564 views) was asked by [*steelerfan*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22792), which makes her the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [How did Mongo "punch" the horse?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60466/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Why did filmmakers choose to portray "What is Sodomy" in this manner?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60268/49) (7 / ~585)
3. [How did Willy Wonka know the Golden Tickets would wind up in the hands of children?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60423/49) (6 / ~106)
4. [Was the lecture in the classroom scene real or fictional?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60276/49) (3 / ~54)

   [Why did the plot instantly skip from the monster's escape to the townspeople's defense preparations?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60322/49) (3 / ~44)
5. [Why did George throw the book into his own suitcase?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60370/49) (2 / ~23)

   [Was it a common practice to pronounce the fare on the cab door in the sixties?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60543/49) (2 / ~14)