# Topic Challenge: Musicals [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

[Due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2390/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2016-09-23 00:00 UTC to 2016-10-02 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about [**Musical films or TV-shows**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_film).<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [musical](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/musical) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 7 and ~52 views) was asked by [*Hilbert*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/41575), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Are the performances on Glee largely the characters' imagination?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61261/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Why Did Milos Forman Change 'Hair' as Much as He Did?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61191/49) (6 / ~53)

   [Why are most of the Disney Princess movies musicals?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61405/49) (6 / ~43)

   [Why did the Chipmunks' sweaters become shorter?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61399/49) (6 / ~30)
3. [Is the phone ringing scene from RGV's Company inspired from another movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61381/49) (5 / ~31)
4. [Why did Riff Randell refer to The Ramones as brothers?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61099/49) (4 / ~44)

   [Do Roxie and her husband get back together in the end?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61084/49) (4 / ~40)
5. [Why Did Tim Burton cut the Ballad from Sweeney Todd?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61145/49) (3 / ~35)

   [Why was the witch so tempted to cross the mirror and get Veer albeit it was getting Jai's soul in exchange?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61138/49) (3 / ~20)
6. [Which songs were performed more than once on Glee?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61206/49) (2 / ~53)
7. [What was the first full-length film that was a musical?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61228/49) (1 / ~70)

   [To what movies do the soundtracks in this Masha and the Bear episode belong?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61239/49) (1 / ~26)