# Topic Challenge: Kate Winslet and her films [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

October 5th celebrates the 41st birthday of renowned actress [*Kate Winslet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kate_Winslet). So in honour of her and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2421/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2016-10-05 00:00 UTC to 2016-10-11 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **Kate Winslet and [the films she was in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kate_Winslet_filmography)**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [kate-winslet](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kate-winslet) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The challenge is over and the only and thus **top-voted question** (with a score of 10 and ~143 views) was asked by [*steelerfan*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22792), which makes her the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Did Caledon and Rose ever have sex?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61751/49)