# Topic Challenge: The Arrowverse [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

This week and the last one sees the season openings for [*Arrow*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2193021/), [*The Flash*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3107288/) and [*Legends of Tomorrow*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4532368/). So [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2403/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2016-10-12 12:00 UTC to 2016-10-23 12:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about the **TV-shows set in the [*Arrowverse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowverse)** (conveniently taggable with [arrowverse](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arrowverse)).

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Comment: Forgot to mention supergirl

Comment: @AnkitSharma Gheez, is it even clear now if that is Arrowverse or not? Wikipedia says *NO*.

Comment: parallel earth but there is a planned crossover

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yeah, tells me as much as I knew before. So is it Arrowverse or not?

Comment: It should be considered like that

Comment: @AnkitSharma Well, Wikipedia doesn't.

Comment: Yeah I know and there is no further plan for Constantine too :(

Comment: The quote from the showrunners in [this answer](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/51298/12783) says that the Arrow-verse (with the hyphen) is Legends, Arrow, and Flash. They then group Supergirl separately. So at least for now, the two are not connected. I guess the idea is that Supergirl could eventually be considered an official part of it, but for the time being, it is a separate thing.

Comment: At-least Vixen is for sure arrowverse ;)

Comment: The opening of Supergirl in S2 now features a shot of the Flash (from last season's crossover) when she talks about new friends. So... FWIW, I'd include Supergirl in any Arrowverse topic.

Comment: @Longspeak I've [opened a question about Supergirl in the Arrowverse](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61915/12783). I've added my answer, but perhaps others have a better one.

Comment: Supergirl is as much arrow verse as Earth 2 is arrowverse. Arrowverse at this point means the multiverse the shows are a part of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted questions (with a score of 5 and ~102/68 views respectively) were asked by [*Oliver_C*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1525) and [*Ankit Sharma*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190), which makes them the winners of this challenge:

## 1. [Do "Flash" and "Legends of Tomorrow" have different rules for time travel?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61980/49)

## [What are all the names from Arrow's kill list and what is the status of these people?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62010/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Where does Vixen S02E01 fall in Arrowverse timeline?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62228/49) (4 / ~43)
3. [Do the showrunners consider Supergirl and Constantine to be part of the Arrowverse?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61915/49) (3 / ~244)

   [How did Jesse run in an eight-like fashion without wearing the special speedster suit?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62234/49) (3 / ~25)
4. [Why does S.T.A.R. Labs look different in Vixen than it does in The Flash?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62246/49) (2 / ~17)
5. [Which actors in the Arrowverse have previously played DC Comics characters?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61881/49) (-4 / ~75)