# Topic Challenge: Dan Brown [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

With the release of [*Inferno*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3062096/) and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2464/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2016-10-24 00:00 UTC to 2016-10-30 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about the **films adapted from Dan Brown's novels** (precisely [the-da-vinci-code](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-da-vinci-code), [angels-and-demons](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angels-and-demons) and [inferno](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inferno)).

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The challenge is over and the only and thus **top-voted question** (with a score of 7 and ~236 views) was asked by [*rand al'thor*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/27759), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Watching order for the Dan Brown films?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62550/49)