# Topic Challenge: Halloween and Horror [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

In celebration of [Halloween](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween) and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2458/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2016-10-31 00:00 UTC to 2016-11-06 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **horror films/TV-shows or films/TV-shows centered around Halloween**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Comment: And here I just finished my horror movie marathon! Should've saved all my questions until this week haha. Oh well.

Comment: @sanpaco I am sure there are more horror film for you to look out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted questions (with a score of 5 and ~97/49/47/27 views respectively) were asked by [*Ankit Sharma*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190) and [*steelerfan*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22792), which makes them the winners of this challenge:

## 1. [What is the significance of the missing mouth in the Silent Hill and Silent Hill: Revelation film posters?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62656/49)

## [What is the significance of Pink Bunny in Silent Hill: Revelation?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62768/49)

## [How did the wolf characteristics get passed onto Laura?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62811/49)

## [Why didn't the witches keep the voodoo doll close to them?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62806/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Why are the asylum guards wearing cages on their heads?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62569/49) (4 / ~131)
3. [Why is Adelaide Clemens wearing seven layers of clothing for Silent Hill: Revelation?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62778/49) (3 / ~59)

   [Why can't Dracula save Mirena from falling even with supernatural powers?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62814/49) (3 / ~34)

   [Are There any Details Regarding Polly's Death?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62790/49) (3 / ~25)

   [How accurate is the language they speak in The Witch (2015)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62835/49) (3 / ~21)
4. [Significance of the numbers next to the people in Anne's drawing](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62831/49) (1 / ~28)

---

<sub>Some of those movie might be rather edge cases with regard to calling them "horror". But to try to be rather inclusive we chose to accept all films that either IMDb or Wikipedia called horror.</sub>

Comment: Hey I got second place!