# Topic Challenge: World War I [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

In rememberance of the end of hostilities of WWI with the armistice on November 11th 1918 and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2433/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2016-11-11 12:00 UTC to 2016-11-20 12:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **[films/TV-shows centered on World War I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_World_War_I_films)**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 6 and ~50 views) was asked by [*ghostdog*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22599), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [How true-to-life was 'Joyeux Noel'?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63405/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Why film in Canada when there's plenty of land in Montana?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63492/49) (3 / ~414)
3. [Does Wolverine fight for the U.S or for Canada in the WWI montage of X-Men Origins: Wolverine?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63130/49) (2 / ~62) *

---

* <sub>While it is quite a stretch to call the film itself "centered on WWI", given that its treatment basically amounts to 3 seconds of opening montage, the question is still remarkable in that it is explicitly about the treatment of WWI within the film.</sub>