# Topic Challenge: Harry Potter and the Fantastic Beasts [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

Last week saw the release of [*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3183660/), a spin-off from the popular series of [*Harry Potter* films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_(film_series)) and itself starting a new series of films in the *Harry Potter* universe. So [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2369/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2016-11-21 00:00 UTC to 2016-12-02 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about the ***Harry Potter* and *Fantastic Beasts* films**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Comment: [Shortcut to the Fantastic-beasts tagged questions](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantastic-beasts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 33 and ~7,937 views) was asked by [*Gray Roberts*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/43021), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [In Fantastic Beasts And Where To Find Them, why are portkeys not used for long-distance travel?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63635/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Is Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them understandable without watching any other Harry Potter film?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63604/49) (26 / ~8,229)

   [Why didn't Harry Potter become an Obscurial?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63587/49) (26 / ~10,204)
3. [Is there any muggle technology that is used in Harry Potter's world?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/64016/49) (22 / ~5,251)
4. [What are all the magical creatures/Beasts in Newt Scamander's suitcase?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63665/49) (13 / ~2,836)
5. [Is it possible that Jacob retained his memories?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63808/49) (11 / ~1,331)
6. [What does the first scene in Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them mean?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63724/49) (10 / ~2,668)
7. [Why does Graves want him dead?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63650/49) (8 / ~1,134)

   [Why does Voldemort use this spell?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63708/49) (8 / ~240)
8. [How does Percy Graves use magic without his wand in Fantastic Beasts?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63614/49) (7 / ~729)

   [How did Newt Scamander realize "someone's" real identity?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63663/49) (7 / ~718)
9. [Why was Frank necessary?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63717/49) (6 / ~253)

   [Is Percival Graves using the Elder Wand in Fantastic Beasts?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63655/49) (6 / ~754)
10. [What is the magical wasp that Newt notices several times in New York City?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63649/49) (5 / ~130)

    [How can a witch/wizard disguise themselves, excluding Polyjuice Potion?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63626/49) (5 / ~164)

    [Why didn't more beasts escape when Newt's suitcase was open?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/64043/49) (5 / ~117)
11. [Did he allow Newt to catch him?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/64118/49) (4 / ~78)

    [What happened to Peter Pettigrew?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63592/49) (4 / ~110)

    [Why MACUSA and not MCUSA (Magical Congress of the United States of America)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63638/49) (4 / ~233)
12. [What is the logic behind the execution procedure in Fantastic Beasts?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63716/49) (3 / ~539)

    [Why was the Obscurus in Newt's case staying in a snowscape?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/64095/49) (3 / ~97)

    [How did the Swooping Evil Venom infused rain affect the magical community?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63854/49) (3 / ~138)
13. [Are there any more movies announced after Fantastic Beasts?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63675/49) (1 / ~148)

    [Why was Harry not able to see Thestrals until Order of the Phoenix?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63710/49) (1 / ~122)
14. [Do wizards regularly wear muggle clothing?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/64058/49) (-1 / ~43)