# Topic Challenge: Hayao Miyazaki and Studio Ghibli [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

Last week celebrated the 15th anniversary of [*Spirited Away*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0245429/), one of the most famous and successful animation films from [Hayao Miyazaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayao_Miyazaki) and his [Studio Ghibli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studio_Ghibli). So in honor of them and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2522/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2016-12-05 00:00 UTC to 2016-12-11 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about the **films from Hayao Miazaki or his Studio Ghibli**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [hayao-miyazaki](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hayao-miyazaki) or [studio-ghibli](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/studio-ghibli) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Comment: Great choice! There's a question I'd love to ask here, but I can't figure out how to frame it. Hayao Miyazaki's films are the only ones I can think of that regularly don't have major antagonists, which I find really interesting - I'd love to ask something about whether there are other studios / directors who also make films with no major antagonists, but I can't think how to frame the question to not be too open-ended. If anyone can figure out what I'm getting at here and how to frame it as a proper question, please ask it for me, and I'll stick a big bounty on it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 11 and ~188 views) was asked by [*SQB*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/9382), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Is there a name for this storytelling technique?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/64363/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Why was Castle of Cagliostro so stylistically/artistically different from Miyazaki's other films?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/64404/49) (6 / ~56)
3. [What changes were made in Princess Kaguya from the original Tale of the Bamboo Cutter story?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/64418/49) (2 / ~20)