# Topic Challenge: Kirk Douglas and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

Last week celebrated the 100th birthday of renowned actor [*Kirk Douglas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirk_Douglas). So in honour of him and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2435/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2016-12-12 00:00 UTC to 2016-12-23 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **Kirk Douglas and [the films he was in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirk_Douglas_filmography)**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [kirk-douglas](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kirk-douglas) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Comment: heh, I haven't seen a single one of his movies...

Comment: @DForck42 I have seen one if cameo counts ;D

Comment: we're challenging you to all your great questions about Kirk Douglas and the films he was in ( Can you please explain for new user as myself how this works ) Thanks

Comment: @JERIAHESIASON You basically just ask on-topic questions as you normally do, just that they get specially honoured when they're about the topic of the challenge.

Comment: Thank you Napoleon Wilson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 7 and ~95 views) was asked by [*Erik*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/26325), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Why did some people feel Lonely Are the Brave was "brutal" and "sadistic"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/64898/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Did "The Final Countdown" inspire "The Philadelphia Experiment"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/65076/49) (6 / ~71)
3. [Why the shift in Ned Land's character?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/65361/49) (3 / ~39)
4. ["I am Negan" lifted from the movie Spartacus?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/65362/49) (1 / ~46)