# Topic Challenge: Video game adaptations [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

With the release of [*Assassin's Creed*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2094766/) and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2397/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2016-12-24 00:00 UTC to 2017-01-06 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **[films and TV shows based on video games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_based_on_video_games)**.

[image]

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

[image]

Comment: Films based on video games O.o, that means I gave wrong entries. I though TV/web series are counted too

Comment: @AnkitSharma Well, they are.

Comment: Wow, all movies on that list have less than 50% rating on Rotten Tomatoes O.o Is a question about 'why such low ratings for these movies' on-topic for Movies.SE?

Comment: @BlueMoon93 [Judge for yourself](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/65835/49).

Comment: Tron was based on the movie. That's why it's the only one that doesn't suck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 13 and ~85 views) was asked by [*Ankit Sharma*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Why did Mortal Kombat: Legacy S01E06 have a special notice added from the director in the start?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/65576/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Why does the DOA: Dead or Alive film have an additional DOA in the title?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/66056/49) (11 / ~1576)
3. [Are there any authoritative explanations for why video game movie adaptations receive poor critical reception?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/65835/49) (9 / ~146)

   [Why isn't Kung Lao in any of the Mortal Kombat movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/65636/49) (9 / ~615)

   [Why did Johnny Cage leave his "friendship" offering after his fight with Scorpion?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/65567/49) (9 / ~156)
4. [In Mortal Kombat: Annihilation, why did Johnny Cage get killed so quickly?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/66051/49) (5 / ~85)
5. [Why did Machinima make Mortal Kombat: Legacy viewing private on YouTube?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/65578/49) (3 / ~66)

Comment: Ask about video game adaptations and 5 out of 7 are about Mortal Kombat (and one more was about a similar fighting movie). Looks like we could have done a topic challenge just about that!