# Topic Challenge: Underworld [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

Last week saw the US release of [*Underworld: Blood Wars*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3717252/), the 5th installment in the [*Underworld* film series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underworld_(film_series)). So [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2529/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2017-01-09 00:00 UTC to 2017-01-20 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about the ***Underworld* films**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 8 and ~71 views) was asked by [*steelersquirrel*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22792), which makes her the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Were Viktor and Alexander Corvinus acquaintances before they became immortal?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/66565/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Why does the Underworld film series avoid female Lycans?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/66677/49) (6 / ~188)

   [Why did Viktor wait so long to kill Selene's family?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/66707/49) (6 / ~59)
3. [What was the location of Andreas Tanis exile?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/66926/49) (5 / ~30)

   [Why is Marcus Corvinus's hybrid nature different from Michael Corvin?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/66577/49) (5 / ~69)
4. [What happened to the humans?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/66630/49) (4 / ~44)

   [What was the Lycan cannon?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/66629/49) (4 / ~26)

   [Why does Viktor say that the sons of the Corvinus clan is a ridiculous legend?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/66482/49) (4 / ~11)

Comment: ***Acceptance Speech***: I would like to thank myself for the nomination of the challenge. I would like to thank Ankit and cde for asking other Underworld questions. I would like to thank cde and Amaranth for answering the questions. Last but not least, I would like to thank Napoleon for sponsoring the challenge ;)