# Topic Challenge: Heath Ledger and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

The 22nd of January marked the 9th anniversary of [*Heath Ledger's*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heath_Ledger) death. So in honour of him and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2486/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2017-01-23 00:00 UTC to 2017-01-29 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **Heath Ledger and [the films he was in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heath_Ledger#Filmography)**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [heath-ledger](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heath-ledger) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Comment: I was tempted to add a Heath Ledger tag to this post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 31 and ~7152 views) was asked by [*A J*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/27264), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Who was the fifth one that was killed by Harvey Dent in The Dark Knight?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/67379/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [How did Alfred's story about the bandit help Bruce in dealing with the Joker?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/67539/49) (24 / ~4990)
3. [Was William based on the real Ulrich von Liechtenstein?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/67449/49) (10 / ~103)
4. [Did Nolan deliberately do the Joker fall scene in reverse to Burton's version?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/67662/49) (8 / ~65)
5. [What is the bird and/or the birdcage supposed to represent while Hank and Leticia have sex?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/67365/49) (7 / ~56)

   [Were four actors initially cast for the role of Tony in The Imaginarium of Doctor Parnassus?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/67499/49) (7 / ~182)

   [Was Jack in love with someone else right before his death?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/67403/49) (7 / ~34)

   [What was the significance of the tire iron?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/67535/49) (7 / ~27)

   [Why were there more than 10 things that she hates in Kat's poem?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/67661/49) (7 / ~461)
6. [Were there early signs Pat liked Kat?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/67447/49) (6 / ~57)

   [Why does Dr. Parnassus keep making deals and wagers?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/67558/49) (6 / ~32)

Comment: **Acceptance Speech:** I'd like to thank Ankit for suggesting the topic and Steelersquirrel and Ankit for encouraging me to participate. I'd also like to thank DrRDizzle and Walt for answering my question that I had in my mind for last one month. And the last, but not least, I'd like to thank Napoleon for sponsoring the challenge. :-)