# Topic Challenge: Keanu Reeves and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

With the release of [*John Wick: Chapter 2*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4425200/) we'll use this chance to look back on lead actor [*Keanu Reeves*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keanu_Reeves)'s oeuvre. So in honour of him and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2528/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2017-02-13 00:00 UTC to 2017-02-19 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **Keanu Reeves and [the films and TV-shows he was in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keanu_Reeves#Filmography)**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [keanu-reeves](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keanu-reeves) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 7 and 399 views respectively) was asked by [*Ankit Sharma*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [What was the point of A Scanner Darkly being animated?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/68877/27264)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [What was the purpose of Johnny Utah firing several rounds into the air?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/68799/27264)(6 / ~86)
3. [Which King Henry were Bill and Ted referring to?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/68626/27264)(5 / ~80)

   [What is the purpose of the specialized subtitles during "The Boogeyman" song?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/68665/27264)(5 / ~57)

   [Was Keanu Reeves cast due to his past hockey experience?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/68798/27264)(5 / ~44)
4. [What illness did Madame de Tourvel actually die from?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/68664/27264)(4 / ~49)

Comment: I wanted to participate in it from the start but didn't got much time. But after enough push from @steelersquirrel tried it and loved the positive response I got. Thanks to all the upvoters and participates to encourage me. And Thanks to #AJ for sorting it all out ;)