# Topic Challenge: Bill Paxton and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

February 25th saw the death of actor [*Bill Paxton*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Paxton). So in honour of him and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2653/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2017-03-06 00:00 UTC to 2017-03-12 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **Bill Paxton and [the films he was in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Paxton#Filmography)**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [bill-paxton](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bill-paxton) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 46 and ~7,389 views) was asked by [*Paulie_D*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/34317), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Game Over, Man...Game Over! - What's the source?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/69675/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. ['Yeah but it's a dry heat' - reference to another film?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/69689/49) (42 / ~8,190)
3. [Could someone actually survive an F-5 category tornado in this manner?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/69950/49) (25 / ~2,802)
4. [Why did Rose keep the Heart of the Ocean so long?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/69669/49) (12 / ~2,698)
5. [Why was "The Shining" playing at the drive-in?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/69765/49) (11 / ~130)
6. [Is Billy Breckenridge gay?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/69763/49) (3 / ~46)
7. [Does Titanic (1997) really show these 3 pictures of Rose Dawson and her new family?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/70015/49) (1 / ~60)

   [In the collage pan of Rose's pictures in Titanic (1997), what was this picture intended to exhibit?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/70016/49) (1 / ~33)

   [Does the cinematic version of Titanic (1997) include Rose Dawson's and J. Bruce Ismay's first steps on the Carpathia?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/70012/49) (1 / ~21)
8. [Where can I find more details of Rose (Dawson)'s arranged pictures In Titanic (1997)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/70017/49) (0 / ~32)