# Topic Challenge: Kurt Russell and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

March 17th marks the birthday of [Kurt Russell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Russell), who looks back on 55 years of acting. So in honour of him and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2497/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2017-03-17 00:00 UTC to 2017-03-26 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **Kurt Russell and [the films and TV-shows he was in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Russell#Filmography)**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [kurt-russell](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kurt-russell) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 16 and ~1,788 views) was asked by [*bureaquete*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/48200), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [In Stargate, what has happened to the children in the pyramid?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/70331/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [In Stargate how did they manage to activate gate back to Earth?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/70329/49) (7 / ~117)

   [Did Napoleon Wilson "reappear" as Snake Plissken?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/70294/49) (7 / ~86)
3. [Was the scene with Kurt Russell and Kate Hudson created for personal reasons?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/70255/49) (6 / ~71)

   [Was Ronald responsible for starting the fire that killed Dennis McCaffrey?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/70429/49) (6 / ~39)
4. [Why isn't Steven Seagal listed in the opening credits?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/70415/49) (5 / ~103)
5. [Did Kurt get close to the fire in Backdraft?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/70232/49) (3 / ~35)

   [Why is Kurt Russell depicted as a Giant in this poster for Big Trouble in Little China?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/70226/49) (3 / ~140)
6. [How did they know what is on the other side?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/70610/49) (2 / ~35)
7. [Why did they reverse the propellers' rotation?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/70615/49) (1 / ~63)