# Topic Challenge: Anime [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

With the release of [*Ghost in the Shell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell_(2017_film)) Hollywood is remaking a [one of the most acclaimed Japanese anime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell_(1995_film)). So in order to celebrate its original version and its entire art form and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2474/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2017-04-01 00:00 UTC to 2017-04-09 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great **questions about [anime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anime)**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add the [anime](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 21 and ~5,404 views) was asked by [*A J*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/27264), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [How does the movie Spirited Away justify its title?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/71368/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [How exactly did Chihiro guess it right in Spirited Away?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/71055/49) (8 / ~196)
3. [What characteristics tie anime styles together?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/71178/49) (7 / ~59)
4. [Is Jack, the right hand of Kaido, breathing underwater?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/71371/49) (5 / ~894)
5. [What exactly are Leila's Geass powers?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/71075/49) (4 / ~32)
6. [Who is the woman Kusanagi saw during the ferry scene?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/71408/49) (3 / ~33)

   [Why do some animes end up with filler episodes?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/71283/49) (3 / ~92)

   [Is Korra a Prodigy as an Avatar?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/71195/49) (3 / ~54)
7. [What happens when two users try to summon same being at the same time?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/71111/49) (1 / ~42)

   [What Mytho's emotion does Princess Tutu's pendant belongs to?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/71192/49) (1 / ~20)

Comment: **Winning Speech** I'd like to thank Ankit Sharma for suggesting the topic. I'd also like to thank Ankit to encourage me watching Anime, which I gave up watching long ago. And the last, but not least, Napoleon for sponsoring the challenge and him and DrRDizzle for suggesting Anime movies.