# Topic Challenge: Saving the Earth [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

In honour of [Earth Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Day) and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2764/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2017-04-24 00:00 UTC to 2017-04-30 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about movies and TV-shows **centering on saving the Earth, be that from environmental deterioration, exploitation, utter destruction,...**

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Comment: *"Saving the Earth [completed]"* Oh... that's awesome, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 26 and ~5,459 views) was asked by [*Gustavo Gabriel*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/42976), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [How can the Axiom computer know Earth is safe based on the one little plant EVE found?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/72252/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Do the Oxygen Torches in the movie "Life" (2017) exist and how do/would they work?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/72293/49) (3 / ~76)