# Topic Challenge: Female-lead films and TV-shows [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

With the release of [*Wonder Woman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Woman_(2017_film)) and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2803/1190) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2017-06-05 00:00 UTC to 2017-06-16 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **films/TV-shows with women as primary protagonists**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Comment: "Primary protagonist" is a tautology.

Comment: I'm afraid I'd be dogpiled for coming here with an Electra question. There's an unwritten Internet agreement to pretend that movie never happened...Hmmm. Perhaps Electro-Woman and Dyna Girl?

Comment: @Gallifreyan I don't know. There can be a multitude of protagonists in a film really, no? We didn't just write this out of nothing and there was *some* consideration put into the wording. ;-)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson _asks on ELU_

Comment: Didn't see this, I just posted a question (does The Force Awakens count?) https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74758/why-did-rey-reacted-that-way-towards-bb8/74761

Comment: @Luciano - I'd give it to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 34 and ~7,289 views) was asked by [steelershark](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22792/steelershark), which makes her the winner of this challenge:

1. [Why would Vivian think that Edward couldn't afford $300 for her to stay the night?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74482/why-would-vivian-think-that-edward-couldnt-afford-300-for-her-to-stay-the-nigh)

The other non closed questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Why did they pick World War I over World War II in Wonder Woman?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74337/why-did-they-pick-world-war-i-over-world-war-ii-in-wonder-woman) (33 / ~8,943)
3. [How can the Bride tell the number of years she was in a coma by looking at her palms?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74267/how-can-the-bride-tell-the-number-of-years-she-was-in-a-coma-by-looking-at-her-p) (27 / ~6,255)
4. [Do Wonder Woman's bracelets have special powers?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74346/do-wonder-womans-bracelets-have-special-powers) (22 / ~4,154)
5. [Why is Edward in a white limousine at the end of the film?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74476/why-is-edward-in-a-white-limousine-at-the-end-of-the-film) (21 / ~6,254)
6. [Were body doubles originally intended to be used before casting the female lead?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74262/were-body-doubles-originally-intended-to-be-used-before-casting-the-female-lead) (13 / ~1,877)
7. [Where did Wonder Woman's sword come from?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74312/where-did-wonder-womans-sword-come-from) (11 / ~4,964)
8. [Can Wonder Woman die?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74372/can-wonder-woman-die) ( 10 / ~6,513)

   [Is Ewan McGregor in The Force Awakens? If so, what was his role?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74595/is-ewan-mcgregor-in-the-force-awakens-if-so-what-was-his-role) ( 10 / ~4,028)
9. [What is the extent of Wonder Woman's powers?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74247/what-is-the-extent-of-wonder-womans-powers) ( 9 / ~252)

   [How did Wonder Woman's shield withstand machine gun fire?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74490/how-did-wonder-womans-shield-withstand-machine-gun-fire) (9 / ~190)

   [Was Hippolyta telling the truth about Diana's origin?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74417/was-hippolyta-telling-the-truth-about-dianas-origin) ( 9 / ~178)
10. [How old is Wonder Woman?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74361/how-old-is-wonder-woman) ( 8 / ~268)

    [Why did Rey react that way towards BB8?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74758/why-did-rey-react-that-way-towards-bb8)( 8 / ~195)
11. [Does Muriel suffer from some type of mental illness?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74731/does-muriel-suffer-from-some-type-of-mental-illness) ( 7 / ~47)
12. [Who exactly is Hippolyta?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74322/who-exactly-is-hippolyta) ( 6/ ~215)

    [How did they sail from Themyscira to London in one night while sleeping?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74682/how-did-they-sail-from-themyscira-to-london-in-one-night-while-sleeping) ( 6 / ~132)
13. [Why did they release clones of Alice and get them killed in Resident Evil: Extinction?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74718/why-did-they-release-clones-of-alice-and-get-them-killed-in-resident-evil-extin) (5 / ~101)

    [Does the fog obscuring Themyscira do anything except hide the island?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74683/does-the-fog-obscuring-themyscira-do-anything-except-hide-the-island) ( 5 / ~77)
14. [Why “Moana” is called “Vaiana” in Europe?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74499/why-moana-is-called-vaiana-in-europe)( 4 / ~193)

    [Why did Michael Bay have an insignificantly small role in Coyote Ugly?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74651/why-did-michael-bay-have-an-insignificantly-small-role-in-coyote-ugly) ( 4/ ~61)
15. [Why did Catherine Tramell use the pseudonym “Catherine Woolf”?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74452/why-did-catherine-tramell-use-the-pseudonym-catherine-woolf) ( 3 / ~34)

    [What was clothes swapping supposed to mean for the two lead characters in Girl Asleep](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74820/what-was-clothes-swapping-supposed-to-mean-for-the-two-lead-characters-in-girl-a) (3 / ~27)
16. [Does Ben Devereaux suffering from stroke saved him from becoming Papa Justify?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74420/does-ben-devereaux-suffering-from-stroke-saved-him-from-becoming-papa-justify) ( 1 / ~40)