# Topic Challenge: Adam West and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

Few days back we saw the death of renowned actor [*Adam West*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_West). So to honor him and due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2821/1190) we'll start a **weekly topic challenge from 2017-06-19 07:00 UTC to 2017-06-25 23:59 UTC** asking for any kind of question about **Adam West and the [films/shows he was in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_West#Filmography)**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add an [adam-west](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adam-west) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 7 and ~79 views) was asked by [Ankit Sharma](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190/ankit-sharma), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

1. [What is the significance of the different avatars of Catwoman in Batman's vision during Concussion?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75069/what-is-the-significance-of-the-different-avatars-of-catwoman-in-batmans-vision)

The other non closed questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Why was the character of Chief O'Hara created](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74988/why-was-the-character-of-chief-ohara-created) ( 5 / ~70)